# If $A(x)=B(x^{100})(x^{50}+1)$ what is possible to say of $a_n$ in terms of $b_n$?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Let $a_n$ and $b_n$ two integer sequences and $A(x)=\sum_{n\geq0}a_nx^n$ and $B(x)=\sum_{n\geq0}b_nx^n$ their generating functions, respectively. Furthermore, one can get $A(x)$ from $B(x)$ using $$A(x)=B(x^{100})(x^{50}+1).$$

Let's suposse I have a expression for $b_n$, is it possible to give a formula for $a_n$ in terms of $b_n$?

I don't think you need this, but explicitly, both functions are $$A(x)=\frac{1}{\left(1-x^{50}\right) \left(1-x^{100}\right) \left(1-x^{200}\right) \left(1-x^{500}\right) \left(1-x^{1000}\right)}$$ and $$B(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2(1-x^2)(1-x^5)(1-x^{10})},$$ and their sequences are [related to the problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4568235/) of counting the number of ways of making change for $n$ given a set of coins.

Comment: Try. It is very simple.

Comment: **Hint:**
$$
\begin{align}
A(x)&=a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_{50}x^{50}+a_{51}x^{51}+\dots+a_{100}x^{100}+\dots
\\
B(x^{100})(1+x^{50})&= b_0 + 0 + 0 + \dots +b_0x^{50}+0+0+\dots+b_1x^{100}+\dots
\end{align}
$$So, most of the $a_n$ must be zero, except for $a_{50}x^{50}$ matches with $b_0x^{50}$, $a_{100}x^{100}$ matches with $b_1x^{100}$, and so on.